# How do I expose a Swift Dictionary as a typed sequence of key-value pairs?

Tags: swift, generics, dictionary

Say I have a class along the lines of:

```
class Foo<K, V> {
    var dict: [K:V] = [:]
}
```

I want to let callers iterate over the key-value pairs in the dictionary, without providing direct access to the dictionary itself. So a caller would be able to write something like:

```
val foo: Foo<Bar, Qux> = ...

for (b, q) in foo.asSequence() {
   ...
}
```

Now, since `Dictionary` conforms to `SequenceType`, coming from other languages, I would expect to just add a method to Foo along the lines of:

```
    func asSequence() -> SequenceType<K, V> {
        return dict
    }
```

However, Swift protocols don't take generic parameters and `SequenceType` is one of those annoying types that "can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements".

I could probably figure out how to wrap `dict` in something that conforms to `SequenceType` (or make `Foo` itself conform to `SequenceType`) but I don't want to start messing around with generators and whatnot until I absolutely have to — this seems like it should be a one-liner if I just understood the available options better. (And it's not clear to me whether that would be enough to get the generics to work such that `(b, q)` has the right types, anyway.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably someone comes up with a more elegant solution, but this works:

```
class Foo<K : Hashable, V> {
    var dict: [K:V] = [:]

    func asSequence() -> SequenceOf<(K, V)> {
        return SequenceOf(dict)
    }
}
```

> ... I could probably figure out how to wrap dict in something that conforms to SequenceType ...

That is exactly what `SequenceOf<>` does for you. From its API
documentation:

```
/// A type-erased sequence.
/// 
/// Forwards operations to an arbitrary underlying sequence with the
/// same `Element` type, hiding the specifics of the underlying
/// sequence type.
```

Answer (score 2):

@MartinR’s solution is good, but I’d take it one step further – if you have a type, and you want to give it a method `asSequence`, then it sounds like you actually want your type to conform to `SequenceType` itself, which is pretty easy to do:

```
extension Foo: SequenceType {
    func generate() -> GeneratorOf<(K, V)> {
        return GeneratorOf(dict.generate())
    }
}
```

Of course, if your class actually exposes multiple things this wouldn’t make sense, but if this particular sequence is fundamental to its being, then this is probably the best option.